# Write regular expression in python to match two specific words, allowing for set number of words between

Tags: python, regex

I am having some difficulty writing a regular expression function in python to identify strings where there are two words, in a specific order, with between 2 to 4 words between. For example, given the phrase 'fired job', I would want the string 'I was fired from my job' to be identified. My initial thought is that the best way to do this is to allow for 2 to 4 spaces between. I wrote the following, which does not seem to work, and would appreciate input.

```
re.search('(fired)(\s{2,4})(job)','I was fired from my job')
```

Comment: You are looking for 2 to 4 spaces *and* other words between the two words. Not just 2 to 4 spaces.

Comment: Use `fired(\s\w+){2,4}\sjob`.

Comment: Use `re.search(r"(?:\s+\S+){0,2}\s+".join(phrase.split()), sentence)`, see [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/RAwLGo).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `(fired)(\s{2,4})(job)` the `\s{2,4}` matches 2-4 whitespace characters and does not allow for optional words between the `fired` and `job` substrings.

Use

```py
\bfired(?:\s+\S+){0,2}\s+job\b
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/th5Gth/1/).

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  fired                    'fired'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (between 0 and 2
                           times (matching the most amount
                           possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \S+                      non-whitespace (all but \n, \r, \t, \f,
                             and " ") (1 or more times (matching the
                             most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ){0,2}                   end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  job                      'job'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
```

**[Python code](https://tio.run/##VcqxCsIwFIXhPU9xzdKEliK6FaSzgy6uWZI2oRHThHsDUsRnj0Enz3Tg/9KWl7geS/EhRcyAlhGcoDnDUxM4j3YGhzFA2OAeTcO8q6Ynq3FaBHJlvkaMg6JW3Vr52neHd/0VK8M7IDkwqEvo1yz4RedpsfOOS2YfZP/aNWYIv95zWcoH)**:

```py
import re
s = 'I was fired from my job'
if re.search(r"\bfired(?:\s+\S+){0,2}\s+job\b", s):
    print("Matched!")
else:
    print("Not matched.")
```

**Results**: `Matched!`